# Выбор сервера для web-проекта (20 тыщ посетителей)

Tags: php, nginx, веб-сервер, highload

Нужно подобрать сервер для мероприятия онлайн. Количество людей будет около 20 тыщ.
Суть в том человек логинится и у него есть доступ к плееру где он будет смотреть само мероприятие.

Как рассчитать нагрузку на сервер чтоб когда перед началом мероприятия вся толпа захочет подключиться к мероприятию и он не упал.

Технологии nginx-phpfpm-mysql

Answer (score 1):

Я бы использовал сторонние средства для потокового вещания видео. 
Ибо 20 тыс. одновременных подключений один сервер не сдюжит. 
Ладно сервер - интернет-канал-то справится?

Comment: а с чего вы взяли, что вещание будет с того же сервера? мне кажется автор хочет встроить плеер со стороннего ресурса.

Comment: ну так зачем? Даже конференции на 500 клиентов делают через сторонние сервисы. 
Достаточно сделать простую форму авторизации на своем сервере и перенаправлять на сторонний сервис и обойтись малой кровью.

Или я что-то не понимаю сути вопроса?

Comment: Через сторонний сервис(перенаправлять), а сам сервак любой, канал 100 мб

Comment: Сервер вещания будет сторонний. суть в том чтоб клиент зарегестрировался оплатил и когда будет мероприятие зашел на страничку где будет встроенный плеер для вещания с какогото CDN сервера. Мне не понятно что будет за 5 мин то старта мероприятия.

Comment: Дык ничего страшного не будет. Ваш сервер должен будет вытянуть 20 тысяч простых обращений. По сути - просто 20 тыс. раз отдать html страницу с кодом авторизации, а затем перенаправить на сторонний сервис. Если у вас есть тестовый веб-сервер проведите на нем "боевой тест", это позволит вам просчитать нагрузку.